# Redirecting to https and subdomain to http

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I have a website which uses an SSL cert on production. At the same time, a staging version (staging.domain.com) should only resolve to http.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.in$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I know it can be done using htaccess, but I simply cannot get it to work.

- www.domain.com / domain.com should redirect to https
- staging.domain.com should redirect to http

Comment: Post the relevant section(s) from the configuration file that you tried that didn't work.

Comment: no reason at all for htaccess. just set up two vhost definitions. one for the www which redirects, and one for staging which doesn't.

Comment: I ll have a look at vhosts, but that would be locally, correct?